# How to customize the osd windows in cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, notifications

I am working on customizing the look of my desktop with the cinnamon.css file in a custom theme that I am working on for Linux Mint, and I came across the osdWindow class in the file, and was able to change the background-color, border-radius, etc. of the volume and brightness osd notifications.

But I was wondering how I might customize the look of it, for example, I would like the osd window to still popup when the volume is changed, but I would like to be able to remove the icon from the popup, or change its layout. I have looked over the osdWindow.js file, and I believe that this would be the place to do it, but I do not know how.

Can anyone help me with figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The trick was to open the `osdWindows.js` file and find the following lines:

```
this._icon = new St.Icon();  
this.actor.add(this.icon, { expand: true });
```

and comment out the second line.  Then I discovered that while this does remove the icons, it does not resize the osd window, so I then found the following lines in the `_monitorsChanged` function, and edited the following lines:

```
this.actor.set_size(this._popupSize, this._popupSize);  
this.actor.translation_y = (monitor.height + monitor.y) - (this._popupSize + (50 * scaleFactor));  
this.actor.translation_x = ((monitor.width / 2) + monitor.x) - (this._popupSize / 2);
```

and edited them to this:

```
let popupWidth = 200;  
let popupHeight = 50;   
this.actor.set_size(popupWidth,popupHeight);     
this.actor.translation_y = monitor.height-3*popupHeight;  
this.actor.translation_x = ((monitor.width / 2)-(popupWidth / 2));
```

This resized the osd windows, as well as performs some repositioning, since I changed the layout a bit.